# php is any easy way to explode sentence with 1-3 words?

Tags: php, explode

php is any easy way to explode sentence with 1-3 words?

```
$str = 'Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001.';
$str = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/i',' ',$str);
$parts = explode(' ',trim($str));
```

now i want to out put the words like this. thanks.

```
$output_array={
"Wikipedia",
"was",
"launched",
"on",
"January",
"15",
"2001", //one word
"Wikipedia was",
"launched on",
"January 15",
"was launched",
"on January",
"15 2001", //two nearby words.
"Wikipedia was launched",
"on January 15",
"was launched on",
"January 15 2001",
"launched on January",
"on January 15" //three nearby words.
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... It seems like you're trying to build a full-text index of your own. In my opinion, so far you've done well. I guess you'll have to re-run through the array $parts skipping by elements of 3 to create a new string. I don't know if there's another method. Perhaps regex may have some solution but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parts = explode(' ',preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/i','',$str));
$output_array = array();
for ($words = 1; $words <= $max; $words++)
    for ($wordIndex = 0; $wordIndex <= count($parts) - $words; $wordIndex++)
        $output_array[] = implode(" ", array_slice($parts, $wordIndex, $words));
```

This is doing exactly what you want. With `$max` the maximum of nearby words. (you may want to set it to `count($parts)`)

It loops through the array and adds to `$output_array` an array of words, imploded by a whitespace.

Comment: set `$max = 3;` only get `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Wikipedia" }`

Comment: You can also get directly an array with the words with `preg_split('/\W+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Yes, that was a suggestion for replacing explode/preg_replace :)